# Angular: Topbar is not rendered after successful authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, angular-httpclient

After a successful login, the token is generated and every component gets rendered except the top bar.
I don't understand what's happening. Below is my code:

**Auth service**

```
private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();

loginUser(authData) {
    this.http.post<{ token: string }>(this.url + '/authenticate', authData).subscribe(response => {
      const token  = response.token;
      if(token) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.authStatusListener.next(true);
        this.saveAuthData(token);
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
      }
    });
}

getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
}
```

**Navbar Component**

```
userIsAuthenticated = false;
private authListenerSubs: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.authListenerSubs = this.adminAuth.getAuthStatusListener().subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
    this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.authListenerSubs.unsubscribe();
}
```

**Navbar HTML**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated">
  <span><a [routerLink]="['/admin/dashboard']" class="tabs">Admin</a></span>
  <span class="space-right"></span>
  <ul>
    <li><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/admin/dashboard']" routerLinkActive="highlight" class="tabs">Dashboard</button></li>
    <li><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/admin/create_category']" routerLinkActive="highlight" class="tabs">Exam Category</button></li>
    <li><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/admin/create_question_category']" routerLinkActive="highlight" class="tabs">Question Category</button></li>
    <li><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/admin/create_section']" routerLinkActive="highlight" class="tabs">Section Marks</button></li>
    <li><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/admin/exam']" routerLinkActive="highlight" class="tabs">Exam</button></li>
    <li><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/admin/question']" routerLinkActive="highlight" class="tabs">Question</button></li>
    <li><button mat-icon-button class="tabs" (click)="onLogout()"><mat-icon>power_settings_new</mat-icon></button></li>
  </ul>
</mat-toolbar>
<main><router-outlet></router-outlet></main>
```

What am understanding is that `userIsAuthenticated` is returning `false` though in service am setting it to `true`.
Please tell me way for modifying this code or any other way.

**P.S. After Logout this navbar will not appear**

Comment: do you use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` in your navbar component, or any of its parents in the element tree?

Comment: no i didn't used

Comment: try injecting `constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}` and calling `this.cdRef.markForCheck()` inside of a `subscribe`

Comment: nope this isn't working